# Convert a datetime string format to local datetime browser using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I try to convert a dateTime string format(**dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**), to local user time. This code is working, but i think it's can be write more simple using **moment.js**... but , i don't understand how.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".DateToLocalTime").each(function () {
            ConvertToLocalTime(this);
        });
    });

function ConvertToLocalTime(div) {
    debugger;
    var input = div.innerText;
    var formatedDate = moment(input, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format();
    var newDate = moment.utc(formatedDate).toDate();

    var offset = newDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    var hours = newDate.getHours();

    newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
    var formatedDateFinale = moment(newDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    div.html(formatedDateFinale);
}
```

For example:
If i have this date: **13/04/2017 09:30:'15** as input, then :

- *formatedDate* = "2017-04-13T09:30:15+03:00"
- *inputDate* = Thu Apr 13 2017 09:30:15 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
- *inputDate.getTimezoneOffset(*) = -180
- *offset* = -3;
- *formatedDateFinale* ='13/04/2017 12:30:15

Many thanks in advance, if you want to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to convert from UTC to local time, with a specific string format.

You're trying to do to much manually. Moment can do this for you.

```
// define the format
var fmt = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss';

// parse your input string as UTC, using that format
var m = moment.utc(input, fmt);

// convert to local time
m.local();

// create the output string in the same format
var result = m.format(fmt);
```

Or simply:

```
var fmt = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss';
var result = moment.utc(input, fmt).local().format(fmt);
```

Comment: I have one more question. If i want the date format to be  displayed according to current culture zone , i read that i can use **moment.lang(currentCulture)**, but how can i get the **fmt** variable according to this culture?.

Comment: You shouldn't chain questions here.  Please ask in a new question, with specific details for that problem.  Thanks.